# Query won't INSERT into table

Tags: php, sql

Before any of you ask, I have an array which prints perfect infomation. I have an implode statement and an insert statement which don't seem to be working and i don't know where the problem is.

A blank webpage is returned with no information. Is there something wrong with my code?

My code is below. Any ideas?

```
$data = '"' . implode('" , "', $news_stories) . '"';
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_story (`title`, `description`, `keywords`, `link`) VALUES (" . $data . ")")or die(mysql_error());
```

Nothing is returned.

Comment: A blank page means you need to enable error_reporting. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  If you have MysQL configured to accept single-quoted strings then the above will work _unless_ an unescaped quote exists in your array. Has `$news_stories` been sanitized?  What are the contents of `$news_stories`? What else have you done to debug?

Comment: what is not working? sql error? have you tried printing the $data variable, sticking that in the query and running it directly in a sql console to see if that works? Is hard to tell anything else wthiout knowing what $news_stories contains, it might be that there are quotes, double or single, left unescaped, ...

Comment: echo the query and try running it directly on the mysql server or via PhpMyAdmin and see if it runs.

Answer (score 0):

add `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of your query to see what exactly the problem is.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_story (`title`, `description`, `keywords`, `link`) VALUES (" . $data . ")") or die(mysql_error());
```

I think the problem would be with the implode function but since i don't know what data is in it i cant say for sure.